# Html inner-text replace special character in C# or Vb.net

Tags: asp.net, html, replace

how to replace special character from client-side html editor post to server in vb or c# whitout replace same charachter in html tags? it usefull to insert to database the correct string.

input:

```
<div class="c1">HELLO YOUR Number 1</div>
```

replace("1","xxx") => replace "1" with "xxx"

output:

```
<div class="c1">HELLO YOUR Number xxx</div>
```

not

```
<div class="cxxx">HELLO YOUR Number xxx</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

once you get a reference to your div from JavaScript or Server side, just call the replace on div.InnerText instead of calling it on the whole page markup.

Comment: how? can you please give me a sample ?